# ReSharper - code style sharing documentation

Tags: resharper

In the ReSharper Options menu under formatting style, it displays what the code looks like after formatting.  Are these stored anywhere?

I'm planning to publish my style settings to a shared location so that other developers on my team can import the settings.  I would also like to have a document out there that people can view before importing the settings to see what the code would look like after formatting.

Is there online documentation somewhere that shows the defaults?  Or rather is there a way to export (or parse if these snippets are stored somewhere on disk) so that I can format it to be displayed without having to go through each setting individually and copy/paste?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I suggest you check this file in with the project as a documentation aide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the R# code style sharing for this:

[image]

Anyhow I don't know a document which shows the R# defaults or any tool to map your current settings to a code snippet or template.

Hope that helps.